# API request called for the infinity times inside react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react and when I get data from the api i store that data inside a hook and when i  console.log that data is called for an infinity times and this lag my website. Here is the code if someone can help i will appreciate =>

````
//importing components
import Main from './components/Main/Main'
import Second from './components/Second/Second'
//import style
import './App.scss'



// api for testing => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState() //here we get the data from the API
  const [drop, setDrop] = useState(null)


  const getValue = (e) => {
    setDrop(e.target.value)

  }

  console.log(data + ' here is the data')




  useEffect(() => {
    let URL;

    if (drop === null) {
      URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'
    } else {
      URL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${drop}?strict=true`
    }


    //getting data from the api
    fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setData(data))
  })

  return (
    < div className="wrapper" >
      <div className="first">
        {data !== undefined && <Main info={data} getValue={getValue} />}
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(drop) }}>testing</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data) }}>testing API</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data.deaths) }}>testing deaths</button>
      </div>
      <div className="bla">
        <Second />
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}

export default App```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an empty dependency array to your `useEffect`. This means it will run only when the component mounts. If you don't pass one in, as you've done, it will run every time the component re-renders. Since the effect sets the state and causes a re-render, this will lead to an infinite loop. Change to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let URL;

    if (drop === null) {
      URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'
    } else {
      URL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${drop}?strict=true`
    }


    //getting data from the api
    fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setData(data))
  }, [drop]) //empty array added here
```

Comment: yeah but like this the main will not be updated with the new data i have a dropdown menu and when you change on it will change the data and the main will not render the new data

Comment: ow fixed thats i added inside [] the drop and drop is the hook that store the value of my dropdown thanks

Comment: @GRIND yeah sorry, add those dependencies to the array and it'll re-run when those values change. I'll add that to my answer. If this answered your question make sure to mark it as the answer